# Adding new columns to R dataframe from another, longer dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes with different information (there's only 1 column which is the same across both dataframes: `subject`). Also, one of the dataframes is longer than the other (more columns and more rows).

So, I have something like this:

```
# drataframe 1

subject var1 var2
101      A    B
102      C    D
103      E    F
...

# dataframe 2

subject  varW varX varY varZ
101        1    2    1    4
101        2    1    1    4
101        4    1    1    4
102        2    1    2    5
102        1    1    2    5
102        2    4    2    5
103        2    3    3    1
103        1    2    3    1
103        4    1    3    1
```

Note that each subject is repeated several times in dataframe 2, whereas in dataframe 1 each subject appears only once.

What I want to do is to append columns `varY` and `varZ` to dataframe 1.

I have tried using `select` (to select those two columns) and then `inner_join` (to join both dataframes). However, I get 3 rows for each subject, because each subject is repeated 3 times in dataframe 2. I would like to have only 1 row for each subject in dataframe 1 once joined, since there is only one value in `varY` and `varZ` for each subject.

In other words, this would be my desired output:

```
subject var1 var2 varY varZ
101      A    B    1    4
102      C    D    2    5
103      E    F    3    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `select`ed columns are having unique values, then use `distinct` and do a join by 'subject'

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df2, subject, varY, varZ) %>%
     right_join(df1) %>%
     select(names(df1), everything())
```

-output

```
#   subject var1 var2 varY varZ
#1     101    A    B    1    4
#2     102    C    D    2    5
#3     103    E    F    3    1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(subject = 101:103, var1 = c("A", "C", "E"),
var2 = c("B", 
"D", "F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(subject = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 
103L, 103L, 103L), varW = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L
), varX = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), varY = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), varZ = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

Answer (score 3):

using `library(data.table)`

```
df1[df2[, .SD[1], .SDcols=c("varY", "varZ"), by=subject], on="subject"]
```

or alternatively (ty comment from @thelatemail),

```
df2[, .(subject, varY, varZ)][df1, on=.(subject), mult="first"]
```

The data:

```
df1 = fread("
subject var1 var2
101      A    B
102      C    D
103      E    F
            ")

df2 = fread("
subject  varW varX varY varZ
101        1    2    1    4
101        2    1    1    4
101        4    1    1    4
102        2    1    2    5
102        1    1    2    5
102        2    4    2    5
103        2    3    3    1
103        1    2    3    1
103        4    1    3    1 
")
```

Comment: Alternative, avoiding the need to group `by=` - `df2[, .(subject, varY, varZ)][df1, on=.(subject), mult="first"]`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = "subject") %>%
  select(-c(varX, varW)) %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1) %>%
  relocate(subject, var1, var2)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   subject [3]
  subject var1  var2   varY  varZ
    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     101 A     B         1     4
2     102 C     D         2     5
3     103 E     F         3     1
```

data

```
df2 <- tribble(
  ~subject,  ~varW, ~varX, ~varY, ~varZ,
  101,        1,    2,    1,    4,
  101,        2,    1,    1,    4,
  101,        4,    1,    1,    4,
  102,        2,    1,    2,    5,
  102,        1,    1,    2,    5,
  102,        2,    4,    2,    5,
  103,        2,    3,    3,    1,
  103,        1,    2,    3,    1,
  103,        4,    1,    3,    1
)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~subject, ~var1, ~var2,
  101,      "A",    "B",
  102,      "C",    "D",
  103,      "E",    "F"
)
```